# Greedy algorithm-maximal minimum average of n pairs

Tags: greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof, induction

Lets assume $2n $ gifts such that each gift $i$ has price $a_i$

The goal is to find a partition of the gifts into $n$ pairs such that each pair $P_i=\left(a_{i_{0}},a_{i_{1}}\right)$ has maximal minimum average IE $ \min_{i\le n}\left\{ \frac{a_{i_{0}}+a_{i_{1}}}{2}\right\}  $ is maximal.

How to get a contradiction inside the induction proof?

So the algorithm I guessed(with a lot of python examples):

```
 1. Initiate a pair array P of size n
 2. Sort the array of prices A in ascending order.
 3. for i<n:
        P.insert(A[i],A[2n-1-i])
```

I struggle to prove its correctness with induction.
for the base case I assume that since $Sol_0=\emptyset$ then $Sol_0\subseteq Opt $ for some optimal solution.
then assuming for $i<k$ that each iteration is good,IE $Sol_i\subseteq Opt $ for some opt.

now the kth iteration, IE $Sol_k=Sol_{k-1}\cup (a[k],a[2n-1-k])\nsubseteq Opt $

This means that the pair we just added is not part of any optimal solution, so there are some $\left(a[r],a[w]\right)\in\widehat{Opt}$  such that $ \frac{a[k]+a[2n-1-k]}{2}<\frac{a[r]+a[w]}{2} $

$(a[r],a[w])$ are the minimum average of some $Opt$

How do I get a contradiction here?

As for the $Sol_{n}\supseteq Opt$ I can say that since we had $n$ iterations and at each iteration we added a single pair, after $n$ iterations we have $\left|Opt\right|=\left|Sol\right|=n$ therefore there is a mutual inclusion.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I get a contradiction that the k'th iteration doesn't break the $Sol_{k}\subseteq Opt $ property?
IE that $ \frac{a[k]+a[2n-1-k]}{2}<\frac{a[r]+a[w]}{2} $ can not happen

Comment: Don't add precisions in the comments, edit your post so that the question is clearly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the induction step that shows $Sol_k\subset$ some optimal solution.

By induction assumption, there is an optimal solution $O_k$ that contains the same pairs as $Sol_k$ except possibly the last pair, $(a[k],a[2n-1-k])$.

- If $(a[k],a[2n-1-k])\in O_k$, we are done.
- Otherwise, $(a[k],a[2n-1-k])\notin O_k$.
  Let $(a[k],a[j])$ and $(a[\ell], a[2n-1-k])$ be the pairs in $O_k$ that contain $a[k]$ and $a[2n-1-k]$ respectively.

  Let $O_k'$ be the solution that is the same as $O_k$ except that pairs $(a[k],a[j])$, $(a[\ell], a[2n-1-k])$ are replaced with $(a[k],a[2n-1-k])$, $(a[\ell],a[j])$.

  Since $a[k]$ and $a[2n-1-k]$ are the minimum element and the maximum element in the remaining elements respectively, we have $a[k] \le a[\ell]$ and $a[j]\le a[2n-1-k]$. So $$ \frac{a[k]+a[j]}2 \le \min(\frac{a[k]+a[2n-1-k]}2, \frac{a[\ell]+a[j]}2),$$ which implies the minimum pair average of $O_k$ is not greater than that of $O_k'$. Since  $O_k$ is an optimal solution, so must be $O_k'$.

  Since $O_k'$ contains the pair $(a[k],a[2n-1-k])$, we are done.

---

If you have to use proof by contradiction, then the existence of $O_k'$ gives rise to a contradiction. This will be an example when proof by contradiction only brings unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P = \{P_0, …, P_{n-1}\}$ be the set of pairs returned by your algorithm and $P' = \{P_0', …, P_{n-1}'\}$ be an other set of pairs.

Denote $f(P) = \min\limits_{i=1}^n(a_{i,0} + a_{i,1})$ where $P_i = \{a_{i,0}, a_{i,1}\} = \{a_i, a_{2n-i-1}\}$ (I got rid of the $\frac{\cdot}2$ part, because it does not change the result) and let $m\in \{0, …, n-1\}$ be an index such that $f(P) = a_m + a_{2n-m-1}$.

Let $i\in \{0, …, 2n - 1\}$ be the index of the element paired with $a_m$ in $P'$. Let us distinguish:

- if $i \leqslant 2n-m-1$, then $f(P') \leqslant a_m + a_i \leqslant a_m + a_{2n-m-1} = f(P)$;
- if $2n-m-1 < i$, then by the pigeonhole principle, there exist two indices $j < m$ and $k \leqslant 2n-m-1$ such that $a_j$ and $a_k$ are paired together in $P'$. If that's the case, $f(P') \leqslant a_j + a_k \leqslant a_m + a_{2n-m-1} = f(P)$.

That means that $P$ is optimal.